# Creating PHP Forms using PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

Can I create Client Forms, Employee Forms, Projects w/ Picture attachment using Pyrocms? Then I will create another form that will link the these forms and create a Transaction Form? I am not expert in PHP but I can create and modify the codes. I am not great at designing or using Code Igniter that well so I want to try out Pyrocms.

Comment: you can buy pyrocms streams. But you must have knowledge of html , php for this

Comment: I do have knowledge in PHP html. actually I started creating the clients form and save it to the database. But it took me a lot of time for a simple form that I can do easily using Software Development PL. I cannot buy pyrocms streams also.

Comment: Can I create Forms without depending on Pyrostreams? If I can make use of my own tables and create my own forms.

Comment: yes it is possible. You can use standard MVC pattren and extend public controller to fit your needs

Comment: ok that made my head spin. thanks